# salesforce1 lightning component learning

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I want to learn salesforce1 lightning component. I want to try it in my developer account for learning purpose. Can anyone provide me some useful link where I can learn basics of salesforce1 lightning components.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a tutorial by Jeff Douglas [Lightning Frequently Asked Questions](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_FAQ) and at the bottom of the developer site under technical resources you will find a bunch more links [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/lightning).

> Technical Resources for Lightning Ready to start developing with
>   Lightning or want to learn more? We've prepared a variety of technical
>   resources that will help you get started building and deploying
>   Lightning Applications and Components.
>
> [Lightning Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/)
>   [Lightning Components QuickStart](https://developer.salesforce.com/resource/pdfs/Lightning_QuickStart.pdf)
>   [Lightning Components Cheatsheet](https://developer.salesforce.com/resource/pdfs/Lightening_Components_Cheatsheet.pdf)
>   [Lightning Components Discussion Forums](https://developer.salesforce.com/resource/pdfs/Lightening_Components_Cheatsheet.pdf)
>   [Lightning Frequently Asked Questions](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_FAQ)

[Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead) has new Lightning badges!

Comment: Would like to add this link as well for basics: http://intmist.wordpress.com/2014/11/02/salesforce1-lightning-components-getting-started-with-salesforce1-lightning-components/

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.salesforce.com/lightning has lots of links (at the bottom) with useful resources for learning.